# Can we extend proof by induction to a bijection (one-to-one correspondance)?

Tags: proof-writing, induction, foundations

#### Viewing a Bijection in Terms of Paths and Cycles

Usually, people induct on the natural numbers.

I want to extend (generalize) the principle of mathematical induction to something other than the natural numbers.

Consider the diagram below:

[image: VISUAL IMAGE OF THE DISJOINT UNION OF SOME PATHS AND CYCLES]

The diagram shows the disjoint union of a collection of paths and cycles.

For me, a bijective function (one-to-one correspondence) describes disjoint union of a set of paths and/or cycles.

No node can have two incoming edges. That would imply that two inputs map to the same output.

No node can have two outgoing edges. That would imply one input maps to two different outputs.

For example, $F(x) = x + 2$ is a bijection on the integers.

$F(x) = x + 2$ represents the union of the following two things:

- a path which passes through all even integers $\{\cdots, -4, -2, 0, +2, +4, \cdots\}$
- a path which passes through all of the odd integers $\{\cdots, -3, -1, +1, +3, \cdots\}$

---

#### Informal Induction on a Bijection

Suppose that we want to prove that every dot, in some set of dots, is black.

Informally, consider the following approach:

- Pick an arbitrary dot $x$. $x$ lies on either a path or a cycle.
- Show that there exists a descendant of $x$ such that the decedent is black.
- Also, we show that there exists an ancestor of $x$ such that the ancestor is black
- Lastly, we show that between any two black dots $a$ and $b$, if there exists a dot of any color between $a$ and $c$, then there exists a black dot between $a$ and $b$.

#### The Principle of Bijective Induction

We define the *The Principle of Bijective Induction* to be the following statement:

> For any set $A$,
>   For any predicate $``\text{is black}''$
>     For any invertible function $F$ whose domain is set $A$
>        $\forall x \in A, x \text{ is black } $
>          if and only if
>        All of the following conditions are satisfied:
>           $\forall x \in A, \text{ if } x \text{ is black } \text{ then } \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } f^{n}(x) \text{ is black }$
>             and
>           $\forall x \in A, \text{ if } x \text{ is black } \text{ then } \exists m \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } f^{-m}(x) \text{ is black }$
>             and
>           $\forall x \in A$,
>             $\text{ if }$
>                     $x \text{ is black } \text{ and } \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } n \geq 3 \text{ and } f^{n}(x) \text{ is black } $
>             $\text{ then } $
>                     $ \exists k \in \{m \in \mathbb{N} \colon \quad 2 \leq m \leq n-1\} \text{ such that } f^{k}(x) \text{ is black } $

#### Another Variant on Induction

> For any set $A$,
>   For any predicate $``\text{is black}''$
>     For any invertible function $F$ whose domain is set $A$
>        $\forall x \in A, x \text{ is black } $
>          if and only if
>        All of the following are true:
>           $\forall x \in A, \exists k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } f^{-k}(x) \text{ is black }$
>             and
>           $\forall x \in A, \text{ if } x \text{ is black } \text{ then } f(x) \text{ is black }$

#### Definition of a Super-scripted Function

> Let $D$ be an arbitrary set.
> For any function $f$ whose domain (set of inputs) is $D$,
>   $\forall x \in D,$
>     $\forall p \in \mathbb{Z},$
>        $f^{p}(x) = \begin{cases}
>  f^{sgn(x)\cdot(\lvert p \rvert -1)}(x) & \text{ if } p \not\in \{-1, 0, +1\} \\
> f(x) & \text{ if } p = +1\\
> \text{the unique $w \in D$ such that $f(w) = x$} & \text{ if } p = -1  \\
> x & \text{ if } p = 0 \\ \end{cases}$

#### Potential Counter-Example

I am a little worried that you could prove that every real number is rational.

Note that:

- for any real number $x$ there exists a real number $y$ such that $x < y$ and $y$ is rational
- for any real number $x$ exists a real number $w$ such that $w < x$ and $w$ is rational
- between any two rational numbers $w$ and $y$ there exists a rational number.

However, the less-than operator $(<)$ is **NOT** a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

For a bijection $\Phi$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, it sort of feels like $\Phi^{-k}(x) < x < \Phi^{+k}(x)$.

However, the iterated bijection $\Phi^{k}$ does **NOT** define a strict total ordering.

Comment: There is indeed a bit of a problem with the suggested induction principle when it comes to uncountable sets. The problem comes from the fact that your conditions only talk about finite iterations $f^n$ of the bijection. Apart from that, the conditions of the form "if $x$ is black then $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $f^n(x)$ is black" seem a bit strange to me. Lastly, the image you have provided does not describe a bijection, as for example 20 is not mapped to anything.

Comment: @Lereau You are correct that my diagram does not depict an bijection. I made the diagram for purposes of intuition and informal understanding. For finite sets, a bijection describes the disjoint union of a set of cycles. For a bijection, every node has one incoming edge and one outgoing edge. However, the starting nodes and ending nodes on a finite path have a missing outgoing edge. I mentioned paths, because, for non-finite sets of nodes, some of the components behave more like paths than cycles. The set $\{x+2: x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ behaves like the disjoint union of two separate paths.

Comment: @Lereau One potential difference between a path and a cycle on the large scale is that the transitive closure of a cycle is symmetric, but the transitive closure of a directed path is not symmetric

Comment: @Lereau You say that uncountably infinite sets are a problem because we only consider finite iterations of the bijection. However, suppose that we prove that, for every real number $x$, any node a finite number of steps away from $x$ is black. The fact that we prove this for **any**  starting point is very different than starting at only one number. If you chose zero to be your starting point, then not all real numbers are reachable from zero, but we allow the starting point to be **any** real number.